# how read all the child elements of xml using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I need to read all child nodes dynamically from node 'book' with id 1 (if you add a child node in xml file but not have to change anything in the code) and put the values ​​of the child nodes into a tableView.

As I can I do?

```
<Book id="1">
    <name>Vishal</name>
    <address>Mumbai</address>
    <country>India</country>
    <editorial>Trillas</editorial>
    <edicion>Segunda</edicion>
</Book>

<Book id="2">
    <name>Vinod</name>
    <address>Delhi</address>
    <autor>Julianne MacLean</autor>
</Book>

<Book id="3">
    <name>Sachin</name>
    <address>pune</address>
    <country>India</country>
    <editorial>Porrua</editorial>
</Book>

<Book id="4">
    <name>Nilesh</name>
    <address>Nasik</address>
    <country>India</country>
</Book>

<Book id="5">
    <name>Video</name>
    <address>Nasik</address>
    <country>India</country>
</Book>
```

Comment: See [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i).

Comment: Xcode can't read XML...

Answer (score 0):

You Can yoe XMLReader (parser)

> XMLReader.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface XMLReader : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
    NSMutableString *textInProgress;
    NSError __strong **_errorPointer;

}

+ (id)parseXML:(NSString *)file_name;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)errorPointer;

@end
```

> XMLReader.m

```
#import "XMLReader.h"

NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"element_text";
@interface XMLReader (Internal)

- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error;
- (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data;

@end


@implementation XMLReader

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public methods

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    XMLReader *reader = [[XMLReader alloc] initWithError:error];
    NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [reader objectWithData:data];
    [reader release];
    return rootDictionary;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:error];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing

- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _errorPointer = error;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [dictionaryStack release];
    [textInProgress release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Clear out any old data
    [dictionaryStack release];
    [textInProgress release];

    dictionaryStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
    [dictionaryStack addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

    // Parse the XML
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    BOOL success = [parser parse];

    // Return the stack's root dictionary on success
    if (success)
    {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = [dictionaryStack objectAtIndex:0];
        return resultDict;
    }

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // Get the dictionary for the current level in the stack
    NSMutableDictionary *parentDict = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

    // Create the child dictionary for the new element, and initilaize it with the attributes
    NSMutableDictionary *childDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [childDict addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];

    // If there's already an item for this key, it means we need to create an array
    id existingValue = [parentDict objectForKey:elementName];
    if (existingValue)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = nil;
        if ([existingValue isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
        {
            // The array exists, so use it
            array = (NSMutableArray *) existingValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create an array if it doesn't exist
            array = [NSMutableArray array];
            [array addObject:existingValue];

            // Replace the child dictionary with an array of children dictionaries
            [parentDict setObject:array forKey:elementName];
        }

        // Add the new child dictionary to the array
        [array addObject:childDict];
    }
    else
    {
        // No existing value, so update the dictionary
        [parentDict setObject:childDict forKey:elementName];
    }

    // Update the stack
    [dictionaryStack addObject:childDict];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    // Update the parent dict with text info
    NSMutableDictionary *dictInProgress = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

    // Set the text property
    if ([textInProgress length] > 0)
    {
        [dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];

        // Reset the text
        [textInProgress release];
        textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    // Pop the current dict
    [dictionaryStack removeLastObject];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
     string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    // Build the text value
    [textInProgress appendString:string];
}


+ (id)parseXML:(NSString *)file_name{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:appDelegate.path];
    if ([file_name isEqualToString:@"yourXMLfilename.xml"]) 
         filePath = [filePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];


    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file_name];

    NSString* theContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


    NSDictionary* dict = [self dictionaryForXMLString:theContents error:nil];
    //This dictionary contains your tags of one record.
    // you can get yor tag value by
    NSString *val = @"";
    if ([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"name"]) {
         val = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];  
    }
}
@end
```